# How do I design a First Persoon Shooter with low bandwidth?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, frame-rate

I would like to create an FPS game but need to manage bandwidth on servers.  What things do I need to design in to do this?

For example should I use TCP or UDP?
What data do I need to send and should I compress it somehow?
I'm thinking I need position, heading, pitch, firing gun boolean.

Other considerations I've missed?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you're in over your head. If you're asking whether to use TCP or UDP, you've got too much to learn to go from where you are now to an FPS. Try something easier, learn the ropes, then see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I direct you to the best online resource I've found on this subject?

[Networking for Game Programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/)

I highly recommend creating a 2D networked game before you even think about making a 3D one. Once you've read Fiedler's articles, you'll have a much better idea of how to accomplish this.

Some general notes:

- All real-time action games use UDP. No exceptions.
- In order to hide client-side input lag, implement client-prediction.
- In order to hide any other lag, implement interpolation and extrapolation.

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

Thats not true. How you can say, that all all real-time action games using UDP. You can't know, because you don't have write these games and only the networkprogrammer of these games knows, what they are using. 
I personally know, that 2 realtime network shooter (one of them are mmo) definitly use TCP network. Its save and better to handle. And at last. If you program UDP to make a game, you must code 80% of the protocols TCP to make your packettransfer save. So, UDP is unacceptable today.

Best Regards.